# Invalid argument error when reading file from Amazon s3 using paperclip and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue reading an XML file after it is uploaded to amazon S3 via paperclip. I've checked and I can access the link using the URL given in the error, all access permissions appear to be fine.

Here's the code I'm using to open the file, which is where the error occurs;

```
f = File.open(@asset.file.url)
```

And the error is Errno::EINVAL - Invalid Argument

I've tried searching for a solution but most seem to be regarding images and not text files.

The S3 bucket is in Ireland region if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the file from your local disk you are reading the file from remote location. Your code should be like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
url_data = open(@asset.file.url).read()
```